# Generated Service with Axis outside Liferay, can't use it inside plugins

Tags: web-services, exception, liferay, axis

Using Liferay 6.2 CE GA6 here.

In my current project I am forced to use a SOAP-RPC webservice generated outside liferay. I have the WSDL file and the procedure I used to get the client was:

- Downloaded Axis 1.4 (same that Liferay 6.2 CE GA6 uses, **I think**)
- Used WSDL2Java to generate Java classes that use the remote service.
- Did a local test with those classes - everything fine.
- Included those classes in a EXT plugin and deployed that plugin to
  Liferay.
- Created Arquilian test and run that test FROM ECLIPSE - Everything
  works.

And now, thinking I got this covered, I created a new Service Plugin, created a test method:

```
public Boolean canICallMyService(){
        MyWsCaller wsClient = new MyWsCaller();

        return true;
    }
```

And **bam**, exception:

> 09:33:21,394 ERROR
>   [http-bio-8080-exec-18][JSONWebServiceServiceAction:87] Unresolved
>   compilation problems: _   The import javax.xml.rpc cannot be
>   resolved_ The method X() from the type XServiceXmlCCServiceLocator
>   refers to the missing type ServiceException_  ServiceException cannot
>   be resolved to a type_ [Sanitized]

I know this must be related with me using Axis libs and Liferay using Axis libs as well, but I can't figure out how to overcome this classpath error. The import in question is jaxrpc.jar, that is included in Liferay's lib (webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib). I have included in ALSO in my EXT plugin's lib directory. If I remove it from the EXT's lib, then the Arquilian test also fails with same error.

I have tried to put the required libs in the lib/ext in tomcat, this just makes Liferay give up on life at start with multiple Axis cast errors on all portlets.

Anyone has any idea what is the correct procedure and how can I replicate it?
I just want to use a Axis 1.4 generated webservice within a Portlet.

My current solution, that I consider kind of lame, is to deploy the webservice as a servlet in the same container and just run calls to localhost/service?q=parametersThatINeed. Works, and no Axis libs conflits.. but not really ideal.

Comment: Add the relevant jars to your build path : axis.jar, jaxrpc.jar and xerces.jar.

Comment: I have tried it, except the xerces. Will try it and report back, thanks for the suggestion!